# Can you include JSON-like data in initial response using connect/express?

Tags: json, http, node.js, express, connect

Can you include JSON-like data in a response using connect/express?

When users hit `'/'` i want to respond with all the assets but also if they are logged in I'd like to send a user object with this payload. Is this possible or do I need to make another request afterwards from the client??

Comment: Can you clarify "respond with all the assets"?

Comment: by that I just mean normal html assets you would serve

Comment: you can send the info along with the HTML, via `data-*` attributes (best), script tags or something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Express' `dynamicHelpers`, or perhaps `helpers`: http://expressjs.com/guide.html#app.dynamichelpers()

Something like this, in your app:

```
app.dynamicHelpers({
  user: function(req, res) {
    return req.session.user;
  }
});
```

In your view:

```
<head>
<!-- ... -->
<script>
  var user = <%- JSON.stringify(user) %>;
</script>
<!-- ... -->
```

Or, you could take a look at the [Express expose](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-expose) module, which is made for this purpose!